# AdSense SDK download

Tags: adsense

Hi I have registered in Google AdSense and I want to use SDK for iOS, but currently I can't find SDK download link.

My application has been approved.

Anybody know how to download this sdk.

I use this link that describe how to use it but does not have link on SDK download.

[AdSense iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-mobile-apps/docs/ios/)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use AdSense instead I use AdMob. Really cool thing!
Very simple and very fast way for provide advertising in your app.